# Send email script works on Win, but not on Android

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtp, kivy, buildozer

This script sends mail when is ran on Windows and Linux, but not on Andorid. What is the issue?

My app requirements in p-4-a are python3, kivy, openssl. Permission is INTERNET. App crashes when I run method below.

```
def send_report(self):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('sender_email', 'sender_pass')
    server.sendmail('sender_email', 'receiver_email', 'Some msg')
    server.close()
```

Comment: Can you add `server.set_debuglevel(1)` (if I remember the method name correctly) and [edit] the transcript into the question?